# (AWS SWF) Is there a way to get a list of all activity workers listening on a particular tasklist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

In our beta stack, we have a single EC2 instance listening to a tasklist. Sometimes another developer in the team start's his own instance for testing purposes and forget to turn it off. This creates problems for the next developer who tries to start an activity only for it to be taken up by the last developer's machine. Is there a way to get the hostnames of all activity workers listening to a particular tasklist ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to get a list of pollers waiting on a task list through the SWF API. The workaround is to look at the identity field on the ActivityExecutionStarted event after it was picked up by the wrong worker.
One way to avoid this issue is always use a task list name that is specific to a machine or developer to avoid collisions.